# Android UI: A gallery viewer that can display full screen when selected

Tags: android, user-interface, gallery

Referring to screenshot 1 below, I would like to create an image viewer circled in blue color with position of image selected circled in red color. I'm wondering which widget to use to create such layout. It looks like a Android Gallery to me however that leads to screenshot 2.

**Screenshot 1**

[image: Screenshot 1.]

**Screenshot 2**

[image: Screenshot 2.]

Screenshot 2 is displaying the selected image from screenshot 1 in full screen view. In addition, screenshot 2 can be scrolled by finger either left or right and correspond to the smaller gallery in screenshot1

Thank you very much for any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you wanna create a new activity in a custom dialog box with scrollable textview at the bottom. Upon clicking a smaller image it will open the new dialog window with a larger picture and the text.

Comment: Hi there, I'm reading about custom dialog box now, I'm wondering how to make the the image scrollable just like a gallery if I put it in a new dialog window?

Comment: surround the imageview or textview or whatever in a scrollable

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have Circle indicator for Image Viewer, here is an example which i came across during surfing: https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow.